# Finding number of open connections to postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I connect to a postgres database hosted on AWS. Is there a way to find out the number of open connections to that database using python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for RDS. There is no direct way via the AWS API. You could potentially get it from CloudWatch but you'd be better off connecting to the database and getting the count that way by querying pg_stat_activity.